# How to stop jQuery from fading on nested div's?

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
var images = ["https://dummyimage.com/600x400/c4c4c4/0011ff.jpg&text=Image+1", "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/c4c4c4/ff0000.jpg&text=Image+2", "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/c4c4c4/fffb00.jpg&text=Image+3"];
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("#dvImage").css("background-image", "url(" + images[i] + ")");
    setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $("#dvImage").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + images[i] + ")");
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
p {padding: 75px 15px 15px 15px;text-align: center;}
#dvImage {background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvImage" style="width: 600px;height: 400px;">
  <div id="text">
    <p>How do I get this text to stop fading?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a background image rotator, that changes images and fades between each image. I've almost got it, but on the site that I'm using it, has a nested image and text, which is also fading. I only want it to fade the background images and not any of the nested div's.

I created an example here with a nested div (and paragraph tag with text).

https://jsfiddle.net/bobthegoat2001/3hrgua82/6/

Does anyone know how I could fix this? Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
<p style="display:none">I guess Stack Overflow wanted some code, so I just put some random here. The jsfiddle will make more since.</p>
```

Comment: I added the code, but in the future try using the code snippet in the text editor toolbar. That way the code and user stays here and don't have to worry about the URL breaking.

Comment: it's not possible to just fade a parent element and not it's children. you *might* be able to fade the background itself though, which would be a css thing, not jquery.

Comment: I guess the most probable answer is **you can't**. The best way will be to make a parent div `position: relative` and put the backdrop (`position:absolute;left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:-1`) and contents (`position:absolute`) in it...

Comment: Hmmm, ok. Thanks for the answers! I'll have to fiddle with it a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position absolute and then set z-index to -1 but you need to move nested div's out of your div #dvImage

```js
var images = ["https://dummyimage.com/600x400/c4c4c4/0011ff.jpg&text=Image+1", "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/c4c4c4/ff0000.jpg&text=Image+2", "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/c4c4c4/fffb00.jpg&text=Image+3"];
$(function () {
    var i = 0;
    $("#dvImage").css("background-image", "url(" + images[i] + ")");
    setInterval(function () {
        i++;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        $("#dvImage").fadeOut("slow", function () {
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + images[i] + ")");
            $(this).fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
p {padding: 75px 15px 15px 15px;text-align: center;}
#dvImage {position:absolute; z-index:-1;width:600px; height:400px; background-size:cover;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvImage"></div>
<div id="text">
  <p>How do I get this text to stop fading?</p>
</div>
```